# Visual Studio Quick Replace Macro with its Definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

I have a C++ file which is littered with macros to the point of being unreadable, and would like a way to replace these macros with their definitions so that I can actually see what's going on.

So far, I've just been right clicking them, choosing "Go To Definition" on the context menu, copy pasting them and manually filling them out. I was hoping VS provides a way to replace a macro with its definition and automatically fill it out and remove the slashes used for escaping each newline?

I've tried using the precompiler output but there are at least some macros I'd like to keep around, and it removes all of them. It also completely throws formatting out the window and you can't know which file each line of code originated from.

So let's say in my table.h file I have:

```
#define TABLE_SIZE 100
```

Then in my table.cpp file I have:

```
int table1[TABLE_SIZE];
int table2[TABLE_SIZE];
```

I'd like to be able to right click and auto replace this with:

```
int table1[100];
int table2[100];
```

Auto filling out any values passed in.

This seems like something that should be very easily possible, but it's difficult to Google search for, since macros normally replace text, hence "replace macro" or other varieties isn't bringing up good results.

Comment: There is a replace in files option and quick replace option. Both utilize the regex if needed.

Comment: Manually substitution macro with its body is not an ideal solution. Typically macro cleanup should involve some refactoring, in this case you may want to declare new constant and use it to declare arrays instead of hard coding magic numbers.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that these macros often have values passed into them i.e. INTF(IMyInterface, Call) whereas somewhere else there's INTF(IMyInterface, Transition) meaning a find and replace of all instances of the macro is not possible. This also does not solve the issue of escaping.

Comment: Most of them are not actually constants, they're large blocks of code that were defined as macros that are only used once in the project, and since there's so many of them it's unnecessarily difficult to read.

Comment: You can get the compiler to write the pre-processed output to a file and then use text diff/merge tools to recombine them see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx

Comment: Although I had tried that solution already, I had not thought of combining them again with a text diffing tool. I may attempt to do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are looking for does not exist in this form. But if you still want to know into what the preprocessor converts the code, you should look at the output.

For MSC (the compiler in Visual Studio), all you need to do is pass the /P option. (I don't recall if it's actually a fancy option is VS or you need to use the additional parameters field to do it.)

But once enables, you should find in the intermediate folder your file preprocessed.

Documentation of the feature: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx